# random stateを変えた値の出力の仕方

Tags: python, numpy

機械学習でrandom stateを変更しながら、出力をしています。
例えば、以下のプログラムで、random stateを0から20まで、全ての値を出力させるようなプログラムは可能でしょうか。
現状では、手作業で0から20まで変更して、いちいちjupyter notebook上で出力しています。

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

forest=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,random_state=0)
data = np.loadtxt('mh.csv', delimiter=',',skiprows=1,dtype=float)
labels = data[:, 0:1]
features = data[:, 1:]
loo=LeaveOneOut() 
scores = cross_val_score(forest, features, labels.ravel(), cv=loo) 

print('Mean accuracy: {:.3f}'.format(scores.mean()))
```

Comment: 回答をつくるための参考として伺いたいのですが、for文がどのようなものかはご存じですか？

Comment: for文が繰り返しを表す、ということをnekketsuuu様のコメントを見て、確認致しました。勉強不足で申し訳ございません。

Answer (score 2):

「ほぼ同じことを何回も繰り返す」というタスクなので、for文を使えばできます。しかも今回は「0から20まで変えながら繰り返す」という場合なので、単純にひとつの変数を0から20まで変化させながら繰り返すだけで良いです。

たとえば下のプログラムは0から20までの数を出力します。

```
for i in range(0, 21):
    print(i)
```

これと同じようにしつつfor文の中身を変えることで今回の問題は解決できます。

おそらく何かしらの資料からPythonのプログラムをコピー＆ペーストしつつ機械学習を学ばれている最中なのだと思います。より発展的なことがしたくなった場合Pythonというプログラミング言語自体をある程度理解しておかないと立ち行かなくなりますので、どれかひとつでもPythonのチュートリアルをこなしておくと今後ラクかと思います。

Comment: for i in range (0, 21):   random_state=i  とすることで、解決できました。ありがとうございました。